# Get Remove And Install as one option with wix toolset

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created Wix set solution. I wanted option to uninstall the previous version from installer window instead of user going to Add Remove program in control panel so I added : `<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize"/>`
This does give remove option but the installer proceeds to finish after uninstall. I want an option where the new setup is installed soon after uninstalling the previous setup, something like Remove and Install option?

Comment: The RemoveExistingProducts action will remove products found by the Upgrade table. Is your Upgrade table populated? Are you using the <MajorUpgrade> element in your wix project?

Comment: What you're referring to is an Upgrade.  As long as your MSI `UpgradeCode` remains the same, and your version number increments in the first, second and/or third fields, running the higher version MSI with the option as you have set to `<RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize">` will cause the existing version to uninstall, followed by installation of the new version.